# Oracle group data by Thursday to Wednesday

Tags: sql, oracle11g

My query groups data from Monday to Sunday. I would like to be able to group data from Thursday to Wednesday. How can I alter the two lines starting with TO_CHAR to do it?

```
SELECT SOMESTUFF
    ,WEEKNUM
    ,WEEKENDING
FROM (
    SELECT SOMEDETAILS
        ,TRXDATE
        ,TO_CHAR(TRXDATE, 'IW') AS WEEKNUM
        ,TO_CHAR(TRUNC(TRXDATE, 'IW') + 7 - 1 / 86400, 'MM/DD/YYYY') AS WEEKENDING
    FROM SOMETABLE
    ) DETAILS
INNER JOIN SOMEOTHERTABLES
GROUP BY SOMEFIELDS
    ,WEEKNUM
    ,WEEKENDING
```

Comment: So you want discard Monday, Tuesday, Saturday and Sunday?

Comment: No, I don't want to discard any data,  I just want my week to be Thursday thru Wednesday instead of Monday thru Sunday.

Comment: well now make more sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `NEXT_DAY(TRXDATE - 1, 'WED')` to find the end of your week:

```
TO_CHAR(NEXT_DAY(TRXDATE - 1, 'WED'), 'MM/DD/YYYY')
TO_CHAR(NEXT_DAY(TRXDATE - 1, 'WED'), 'IW')
```

What week number do you expect?

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I'm thinking the first Wednesday of the year would be the last day of week one. So I could slightly change your second line of code to be:TO_CHAR(NEXT_DAY(TRXDATE - 1, 'WED'), 'IW')-1 AS WEEKNUM

Answer (score 0):

Easiest solution is to simply add one to the weeknum when the date is Wed-Sunday (or subtract if it's Monday or Tuesday).  Something like this would work

```
TO_CHAR(TRXDATE, 'IW') + CASE 
                            WHEN TO_CHAR(TRXDATE, 'D') > 2 THEN 1 
                            ELSE 0 
                         END AS WEEKNUM
```